# How do you apply a style to icon of type IIconProps in Fluid UI?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, office-fabric, fluent-ui

I have button like the sample below with an icon (addFriendIcon).

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/button

How do I add a style to this icon?  For example change the color?

---

import * as React from 'react';
import { ActionButton, IIconProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

const addFriendIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'AddFriend' };

export const ButtonActionExample: React.FunctionComponent = props => {

return (

Create account

);
};

Comment: Do you have a working example you can provide? If it's a react component, are you able to use `className`?

Comment: Here's a codepen from the official MS fluid site

https://codepen.io/evileddie/pen/zYqvjpQ?editable=true%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Ffluentui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it the Fluent UI way, just add the according styles to the IIconProps:

```js
const addFriendIcon: IIconProps = {
  iconName: 'AddFriend',
  styles: {
    root: { color: 'red' }
  }
};
```

Here is the adjusted codepen: https://codepen.io/alex3683/pen/RwarOrb

Comment: can we change the color of the icon to comething onClick? Can you please share that code as well?

Comment: I modified the codepen: https://codepen.io/alex3683/pen/RwarOrb